# Spark SQL: column values can only be a combination of A,T,G,C or N

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to query a spark table to find all rows in the 'ref' column that contain letters that are not A, T, G, C or N.

A valid result should only contain those letters, and can contain any length or combination of those letters.

For example:

Valid = AA, ATTTGGGGCCCC, C, G, TTG, N, etc.

Invalid = P, ., NULL

The following query is returning columns with single nucleotides only:

```
SELECT ref
from test_set
where ref not in ('*A*', '*T*', '*G*', '*C*', '*N*')

ref
1   T
2   C
3   T
4   C
5   T
```

The following query works in impala sql, but not spark, and is also pretty ugly:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(ref, 'A', ''), 'T', ''), 'G', ''), 'C', ''), 'N', '')
    from spark_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I figured it out:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(ref, 'ATGCN', 0)
from test_set
```

Or

```
SELECT alt 
FROM test_set
WHERE regexp_extract( alt, '([^ACGTN.])', 0 ) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did not want to use regexp_extract, the same result is obtainable by performing:

```
SELECT ref
from test_set
where not (
            ref like '*A*' or
            ref like '*T*' or
            ref like '*C*' or
            ref like '*G*' or
            ref like '*N*'
          )
```